Cannot access AI Search anymore from Azure Portal after setting a private endpoint
I am accessing Azure AI Search from a Web App. Hence, I have set:

Virtual Network with 2 subnets, one for AI Search and one for Web App
Created a private endpoint from AI Search to give access to Web App
Restricted networking from AI Search to selected addresses (my IP)

It works perfectly on the application. However, I cannot access indexes, indexers or search explorer anymore from Azure Portal or from my local machine (my  IP).
{"message":"Failed to fetch","stack":"TypeError: Failed to fetch\n at https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/BeUd4hajqUig.js:113:24084","isError":true}

How can I keep AI Search resource secure (avoid public access) while keeping access to it from Azure Portal and localhost?
I even tried open it again to Public Access, but it does not work. Seems that I have to delete the Private Endpoint, which defeates the purpose.

try to add your ip address in network settings.

I already tried that (3rd bullet point)


Cannot access AI Search anymore from Azure Portal after setting aprivate endpoint

Access to indexes, indexers, and other top-level resources in the Azure portal is restricted because the Azure portal's IP address is not allowed in the firewall settings.
To resolve the issue, you can add the Azure portal's IP address to the firewall settings by following steps.

Get the portal IP of AI Search using nslookup <Search service url>

 Ex: nslookup sample-ai.search.windows.net


Copy the IP address 72.152.58.118, add it to the AI firewall settings, and enable the Allow Azure services option.

After adding the portal IP, wait for some time to allow the network rules to take effect before testing
To enable the connection from the web app to AI Search, ensure that a NAT gateway is created within the same subnet as the web app, and allow the same outbound IP in the AI firewall settings
Reference: Allow access from the Azure portal IP address and follow the Stack Link for NAT-related issue.
